# Ready API | Groovy script to pass a variable value as an input of a field for Mongo DB collection

Tags: mongodb, groovy, robo3t, ready-api

I have a mongo DB collection with document structure as below

```
{
_id : ObjectId("5e66a38b478d946943329bba"),
name : "Tom",
age : 26,
ID : "SD34re",
Gender : "Male"
}
```

I'm using groovy script in Ready API to make Mongo DB connection and fetch above document. Now, I need to pass a dynamic value from variable "SSN" to ID value above.
How can I do it using groovy script in Ready API.

Ex:

```
def SSN = context.expand('${#TestCase#SSN}')
```

SSN to be passed as below in document using groovy script in ReadyAPI. How can I achieve it?

```
{
_id : ObjectId("5e66a38b478d946943329bba"),
name : "Tom",
age : 26,
**ID** : **SSN**,
Gender : "Male"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the groovy script, set the result property to your ssn

```
def sSN = context.expand( '${#TestCase#SSN}' )

result =  sSN
```

in your test step/mongoDB script, you can reference the result property using property expansion  `${Groovy Script#result}` e.g.

```
{
    ID : ${Groovy Script#result},
}
```